# Same form in multiple locations in Thymeleaf 3 & Spring 4

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'd like to have my login form (for example) on multiple pages, and I want to pre-populate it with the current user's login (assuming that user is recognized via cookie). But I don't want every controller method for every possible page to have to provide a LoginForm bean for the form. I do want all the validation magic when the form is submitted, and then of course I want the result of the form to the same page the user was on when they submitted it.

I can't quite figure out how to accomplish this right now. Is it even possible?

EDIT:

I've got a Thymeleaf form like this:

```
<form action="#" data-th-action="@{/users/login}" data-th-object="${loginForm}" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Username" data-th-field="${loginForm.login}">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" data-th-field="${loginForm.password}">
    <button type="submit" name="login">Sign in</button>
    <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
</form>
```

If I don’t create a `LoginForm` (my class) bean and stick it in the model under `loginForm`, then I get an exception on GET, when rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the LoginForm to multiple controllers, rather, you can centralize your code at a single place with a http filter by validating the Login form for the required urls as below:

**LoginFormValidationFilter class:**

```
@Component
public class LoginFormValidationFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String url = request.getRequestURL();
    if(url.equals(YOUR_LOGIN_URL)) {
        //validate the request here for the required urls
        //If request is invalid, send an error message back
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

**Web.xml filter mapping:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFormValidationFilter </filter-name>
    <filter-class>xyz.LoginFormValidationFilter </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFormValidationFilter </filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hmm. My concern is not with the validation, it's simply with GETting the page on which the form exists (not even worried yet about submitting the form). Thymeleaf complains that there's no `loginForm` bean. I edited my question with a stripped-down version of my form.